# Knockout Multi-page Script

Tags: knockout.js

I got a question.

Let's say I got 1 knockout model used by 2 pages ( page1.html / page2.html ).

How do I, for instance, alert page2 that an observable's value has been changed in page1 ?

I just need a general explaination.

Thank you very much for your time, good Sirs !

[ What I want to do is : Page1 is a controller [( in which I modify the observables - for example: I tell how I want the information to be shown in page2 ]

In page2 I am displaying the information by the way I have selected in page1.

[for example: I want to have a ko.showOnDashboard(true) and depending on the circumstance, I wanna set it to false or let it be like this and depending on it, show the element on page2 or not ]

@ I'm a newbie with knockout :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is typically solved in one of 2 ways:

Either define a property on the parent context accessible by both *pages* (in your example), eg. an "app" context, then access that property in your Knockout views as `$parent.<property>`. This is easy as it fits the familiar practice to structure functionality in nested namespaces.

Or use the [publish/subscribe design pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#observerpatternjavascript). The advantage of using this method is that components (in this case, pages), stay more loosely decoupled because the values are passed from one page to another as parameters published on a **topic** or **channel**. R. Niemeyer has built [the ko.postbox library](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox) for this kind of concern. The example below shows a minimal vm where the 'displayname' property subscribes to the 'name-value' topic, and will update its value every time page 1's 'name' property changes.
To see the complete implementations side by side, have a look at [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3ynahms/1/).

```
var app = {
  page1: new Page(1),
  page2: new Page(2)
};
app.page1.name = ko.observable().publishOn('name-value');
app.page2.displayname = ko.observable().subscribeTo('name-value');

ko.applyBindings(app2, document.getElementById('method2'));
```

Comment: Cant I use the localStorage ?

Comment: @Florin if your app is on 2 different HTML pages, you can use localStorage. But you could use cookies as well then. However given that your question is about "Knockout multi-page script" it would be more logical that you are talking about a Single-Page Application with multiple 'virtual' pages. If this is not the case your question is badly worded.

Comment: Yeah, I was talking about two different pages, but I appreciate your answer aswell... imma need it in the future. Thank you a lot, imma use localStorage for the moment !